# a.e convergence does not imply convergence in $L^{p}$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Do you have an example of $f_n$ which converges a.e  but  failed to converge in $L^{p}$? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: (The Steinhaus Probability Space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$ converges everywhere to $0$ on the line.